# Save vector layer and update .qgs project file (PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgs

Need help to solve the following use case:

1. QGIS started with new project (no layers)
2. New layer is created programmatically and data is populated:

   ```
   vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")
   pr = vl.dataProvider()
   vl.startEditing()     
   <... put data into vl>
   vl.commitChanges()
   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
   ```
3. New layer is saved as shapefile:

   ```
   QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vl, "c:\\temp\\my_shapes.shp", "CP1250", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
   ```
4. Then I assume I need  to update my layer to change data type from "memory" to "ogr" with the path to shapefile from step #3.
5. Then update project file with this info; so the next time this project is loaded - the layer will read data from my_shapes.shp.

I "kind of" know how to make these #4 and #5 steps using QGIS UI:

- save layer as shapefile plus set "Add saved layer to map" check box.
- delete original layer
- save project

Shall I implement these steps programmatically or there is better way?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot Gcarrillo...third time already!..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the memory layer at all?

Have a look at the "directly from features" example in the [PyQGIS cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#writing-vector-layers) to see how to create a persistent Shapefile from features, so that you avoid creating a memory layer.